# Cannot get app root for OrigenTesters

Tags: origen-sdk

When running a standard test program flow generation command in Origen I got an error I have never seen before:

```
COMPLETE CALL STACK
-------------------
Something went wrong resoving the app root in OrigenTesters
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/flow.rb:152:in `get_app'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/flow.rb:141:in `flow_sig'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/flow.rb:68:in `model'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/flow.rb:42:in `at_flow_start'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/generator.rb:42:in `at_flow_start'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen.rb:577:in `reset_interface'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/generator/flow.rb:34:in `create'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/origen_ext/generator/flow.rb:41:in `create'
/work/locn/myserver/93k-groups-IO/User/myproduct/myproduct_pcie/pcie/src/origen/pcie_flow.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/generator.rb:19:in `load'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/generator.rb:19:in `execute_source'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/generator/job.rb:134:in `run'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/origen_ext/generator.rb:18:in `block in generate_program'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:85:in `block in resolve_files'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:71:in `each'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:71:in `resolve_files'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/origen_ext/generator.rb:14:in `generate_program'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/application/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in launch'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/application/runner.rb:140:in `record_invocation'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/application/runner.rb:75:in `block in launch'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:392:in `preserve_state'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/application/runner.rb:18:in `launch'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/origen_testers-0.15.0/lib/origen_testers/origen_ext/application/runner.rb:21:in `launch'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/commands/program.rb:67:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/commands/program.rb:50:in `_with_doc_tester'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/commands/program.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/commands.rb:233:in `require'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/lib/origen/commands.rb:233:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/bin/origen:172:in `require'
/home/user/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7f825afec037/bin/origen:172:in `<top (required)>'
/work/locn/myserver/93k-groups-IO/User/origen/ppekit/lbin/origen:17:in `load'
/work/locn/myserver/93k-groups-IO/User/origen/ppekit/lbin/origen:17:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrigenTesters is trying to work out who owns the current flow file that it is generating (which looks like it is: myproduct/myproduct_pcie/pcie/src/origen/pcie_flow.rb).

It expects that either to be the current top-level app, or one of its plugins.

To work out the owner, it is trying to backtrack from the location of the flow file to find the Origen root directory.
Here it is failing because it seems like maybe this flow file does not live within an Origen application?

Here is the code that is generating the error: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/flow.rb#L146

It is basically backtracking from myproduct/myproduct_pcie/pcie/src/origen/pcie_flow.rb until it finds a config/application.rb file which lets it know it has found the app root.

I would guess here that maybe you are running a program flow file which lives external to an application.

Origen expects that all test program flow files live under the program/ directory of either the current top-level application, or a plugin.

Comment: thx @Ginty.  We dynamically set symlinks in the program dir based on a user YAML config file so perhaps something went wrong with that.  But if the symlink didn't exist then chicken and egg...stay tuned.

Comment: the user did have the config file syntax backwards such that he was supplying a flow file path that was not within the app working space.